Azure openai client Behind APIM
I have access to azureopenai, but recently we moved behind APIM to have personal access keys.
Previously i used this script fine:
from openai import AzureOpenAI


AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY = 'KEY'
azure_endpoint = "ENDPOINT"
deployment_name = "DEPLOYMENT_NAME"

client = AzureOpenAI(
  api_key = AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
  api_version = "Version",
  azure_endpoint =azure_endpoint,
)



def get_response_enrich():

    completion = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="datascience-nonprod",

        messages=[
            {"role": "system", "content": "name a country in europe"},
            {"role": "user", "content": """ you're a helpful assistant"""}
        ],
        temperature=0,
    
    return completion.choices[0].message.content 

but know our url looks like  apim_url = azure_endpoint = "https://xy-apim-XXX.azure-api.net/"
and the same client call returns:
"openai.NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'statusCode': 404, 'message': 'Resource not found'} "
The curl or request calls are working just fine
import requests
import json

# Set the parameters
apim_url = "https://xy-apim-XXX.azure-api.net/"
deployment_name = "DEPLOYMENT_NAME"
api_version = "Version"
subscription_key = ""

# Construct the URL and headers
url = f"{apim_url}/deployments/{deployment_name}/chat/completions?api-version={api_version}"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key
}

Any idea what is going wrong here?
Thanks.

it needed a "default_headers" to be added to the client:
default_headers=
    {
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "YOUR_KEY"
    }

